# Assuming secp256k1 curve and given fixed (but random) $h$ and $d$ values, is it possible to calculate a $k$ such that $h\equiv(k\,G)_X\,(k-d)\pmod n$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

For generator point $G$ in the [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsection.2.4) curve, I want to find a value $k$ such that:
$$h\equiv(k\,G)_X\,(k-d)\pmod n$$
where $n$ is the group order, and $(k\,G)_X$ indicates the x-coordinate (mod n) of the resulting point after the multiplication by $k$. Assume $h$ and $d$ are fixed scalar values that I've been given.

Is it possible to calculate $k$?

Without the multiplication by $(k - d)$, this would just be the ECC discrete log problem. Does having that extra multiplication make it easier to calculate some $k$, or is there a way to show that it still reduces to the discrete log problem?

In my experiments with smaller fields, it appears that no such $k$ value exists about 35% of the time.

Comment: You should state your question in the text, not only in a title

Comment: Do you expect anyone to be able to decipher what you've written?

Comment: It seems that you decided that the problem with your first incomprehensible post was that it provided *too much* context: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442353/given-a-fixed-hash-value-h-and-private-key-p-is-it-possible-to-find-a-nonce

Comment: @JBL , is it still incomprehensible? Obviously I'd like to be understood. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This kind of mixing of operations always gives me pimples. Here the $x$-coordinate is an element of the field $\Bbb{F}_p$. There simply isn't a well-defined multiplication involving it with respect to the modulus $n\neq p$. I can guess what you mean by the product (take the smallest non-negative integer in the coset of the $x$-coordinate, and magically transform that to a residue class modulo $n$), but this mixing throws all the algebra out of the window.

Comment: Basically because $\gcd(n,p)=1$ we can say that, suitably interpreted, $k=1$ (nearly) always works. In the field $\Bbb{F}_p$ we have $x=x+ap$ for all integers $a$. So we have the congruence
$$h\equiv (x+ap)(1-d)\pmod n.$$
If also $\gcd(1-d,n)=1$ then this congruence will be satisfied by some $a$.

Comment: In other words, in the DLP of the curve you are comparing the points (or their $x$-coordinates as that amounts to almost the same thing). True, the solution $k$ is only determined modulo $n$, but the coordinates are modulo $p$. When you try to mix modulo $p$ and modulo $n$ basically non-sense comes out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , Sorry, I should have been clearer. (kG)x should be the x coordinate mod n. If it helps, this is based on the ECDSA signature scheme. I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to have a valid signature pair (r, s) where r == s. This can be done trivially using an existential forgery, but that requires breaking the hash function.

Comment: crossposted with [cryptogtaphy.se](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/101305/18298)

Comment: It is much more comprehensible than it was before, but it is still extremely far from self-contained.  I don't know if, under any circumstances, the question you're asking would attract answers, but I think it would have been more likely if the question contained enough information for a person to try to solve it.  (Following your link, I still can't really make sense of what key information in the question is: is $n$ the parameter that gets larger and smaller?  What does the operation $(k G)_X$ actually mean?)

Comment: @JBL *n* is the group order (ie - the number of unique points on the elliptic curve that are generated by scalar multiplication of the generator point (G) by members of the given field. This is all described on page 3.). (kG)x is scalar multiplication of the generator point by some integer, k (from [1, n-1]), and taking the x-coordinate of the resulting point.

Comment: I am not, personally, requesting that you explain this to me, I am merely pointing out that your question is on a specialized topic and does not contain sufficient information for someone who is not intimately familiar with it to make sense of it.  (Probably the cryptography forum is a better venue.)

Comment: @JBL I did also post it on that forum, but I think the link does include sufficient information. It would take up quite a bit of space to fully explain scalar elliptic curve multiplication, for instance.